# How To Make PHP Only Process Variables Submitted From Same Server?

Tags: php

I have this case :

I have a file named form.php and it contains just simple HTML form with POST method and the 'action' file of that form always on different file, let's say : action.php. all of this scripts stored under a domain named : realdomain.com (just an example).

today, I created a fake form from another domain (example : fakedomain.com), then I put this : `action="http://realdomain.com/action.php"` then hit the submit button and action.php on realdomain.com can't distinguish if it's from realdomain.com or fakedomain.com and let it goes through just like that...

Then I have an idea to put some 'filter' on the action.php to ONLY process the variables submitted if the referred domain is realdomain.com using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

But again, in some forums or blog post, this method is not reliable at all since HTTP_REFERER can be faked too.

So, how to validate this? I mean, how to make action.php ONLY process variables submitted from same server?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330811/how-can-you-make-a-php-script-only-answer-requests-made-from-the-same-server?rq=1

Comment: http://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-CSRFP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement CSRF protection in your form, a good tutorial: http://phpmaster.com/preventing-cross-site-request-forgeries/

Sorry for the short answer but I am writting on an iphone.